scipy coo_matrix consider some small numbers as 0.0 but still put in sparse matrix
I use some python and numpy/scipy code and produce a sparse array:
<COOrdinate sparse array of dtype 'float64'
    with 21 stored elements and shape (403, 196)>
  Coords    Values
  (206, 138)    0.0
  (206, 139)    0.23614037219163428
  (206, 140)    0.2366397154157327
  (206, 141)    0.236805402497099
  (206, 142)    0.0
  (207, 138)    0.3928269859331709
  (207, 139)    0.3939331263543298
  (207, 140)    0.3995270442982785
  (207, 141)    0.3821409243437723
  (207, 142)    0.3638856690042628
  (208, 138)    0.3935915394673921
  (208, 139)    0.3957499496341213
  (208, 140)    0.39550968408901105
  (208, 141)    0.38493115738953887
  (208, 142)    0.0
  (209, 138)    0.0
  (209, 139)    0.3917329284904307
  (209, 140)    0.39178317681678937
  (209, 141)    0.3796339720019004
  (210, 139)    0.0
  (210, 140)    0.40025290199002156

I was expecting:
<COOrdinate sparse array of dtype 'float64'
    with 21 stored elements and shape (403, 196)>
  Coords    Values
  (206, 139)    0.23614037219163428
  (206, 140)    0.2366397154157327
  (206, 141)    0.236805402497099
  (207, 138)    0.3928269859331709
  (207, 139)    0.3939331263543298
  (207, 140)    0.3995270442982785
  (207, 141)    0.3821409243437723
  (207, 142)    0.3638856690042628
  (208, 138)    0.3935915394673921
  (208, 139)    0.3957499496341213
  (208, 140)    0.39550968408901105
  (208, 141)    0.38493115738953887
  (209, 139)    0.3917329284904307
  (209, 140)    0.39178317681678937
  (209, 141)    0.3796339720019004
  (210, 140)    0.40025290199002156

I tried to print:
np.set_printoptions(precision=100, suppress=True)
print(coo[0].toarray()[206,138])

it gives me 0.0 or np.float64(0.0) if I do not write print in jupyterlab
But not something like 1.14514e-20

I can't help but ask：if numpy think this as 0.0, why it is shown in the sparse array, not an empty value?

How was the COO created?

this relates to a ~1000 lines of python code and processing several GBs of astronomical data

I am looking at eliminate_zeros but I cannot understand how to use this. This is an 'in place' method and I do not understand how to use it. It always returns None.

Inplace means it changes the matrix data directly.  It does not return a new matrix. Look at the eliminate code.  It tests self.data != 0.  It does not test for near-zeros, shch as what you might get with floats.

I can't test your data to see just how close/exact your zeros are.

The reason I ask about how the matrix was created is that 0s are handled differently depending on the method.
To illustrate:
In [129]: from scipy import sparse

Make a sparse matrix with a small new 0 and an actual 0:
In [130]: x = np.array([[1,2,1e-20],[3,0,4.1]]);x
Out[130]: 
array([[1.0e+00, 2.0e+00, 1.0e-20],
       [3.0e+00, 0.0e+00, 4.1e+00]])

With the coo_matrix constructor:
In [131]: M = sparse.coo_matrix(x); M
Out[131]: 
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [132]: print(M)
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (0, 1)    2.0
  (0, 2)    1e-20
  (1, 0)    3.0
  (1, 2)    4.1

But with an alternate input, specifying all elements and their coordinates:
In [133]: M1 = sparse.coo_matrix((x.ravel(),([0,0,0,1,1,1],[0,1,2,0,1,2]))); M1
Out[133]: 
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
    
In [135]: print(M1)
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (0, 1)    2.0
  (0, 2)    1e-20
  (1, 0)    3.0
  (1, 1)    0.0
  (1, 2)    4.1

The (1,1) point is still there.  It took the inputs exactly as I provided them.
eliminate_zeros can get ride of this 0, with the self.data!=0 masking test.
In [137]: M1.eliminate_zeros(); M1
Out[137]: 
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

It did not get rid of the 1e-20 near zero.
The [131] case uses the equivalent of
In [138]: np.nonzero(x)
Out[138]: (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 2], dtype=int64))

to find the coordinates of the nonzero terms.
The COO created with (data,(x,y)) inputs can have duplicate coordinates.  When converted to CSR those duplicates are summed.  If they sum to 0, you still need to apply elimate_zeros.

I use the specifying all elements and their coordinates method since the data and coords are calculated separately. Now I can use .eliminate_zeros() to get rid of it.
